# Getting specific SPFile from document library

Tags: document-library, splistitem, spfile, splistitemcollection

I have a Document Library called "x" with file named "y".  I am curious what the best way to get the SPFile object for the specified SPListItem.  Currently I am using this:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["x"].Items[0].File
```

I don't like using [0] to get the SPListItem... interested in reccomendations

TIA

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but Items[0] will just get you the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more searching and found this as the answer...LINQ to the rescue.

```
        SPList csvList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[libraryName];

        SPFile file = csvList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
                                   .Where(x => x.Name.Equals(fileName))
                                   .Select(x => x.File)
                                   .First();
```

Comment: Note that SPWeb.Lists[libraryName] and SPList.Items incur significant performance costs for large lists. Should be avoided in general as best practice. You should be using GetFile() as Rich suggests

Comment: Good point...in this instance the list will always be very small.  Which part of this solution in particular incurs the performance hit?

Comment: Using the string index SPWeb.Lists[string ListName], behind the scenes the API fetches metadata for all lists and then a for loop to find a matching name. With [Guid] or [index] it fetches directly the corresponding list.

Comment: Same for SPList.Items, your LINQ query will fetch all items and loop through them to execute the Where(). Using a targeted CAML query is better, or in your case GetFile directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the SPWeb [GetFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063.aspx) method to retrive the SPFile located at a specified url. Try something like this:

```
SPFile file = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile(string.Format("{0}/{1}", x, y));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote
>   I don't like using [0] to get the SPListItem...interested in reccomendations

Well, SPList.Items[0] syntax fetch ALL THE DATA from SharePoint and after - give you item by index. That's a common behavior.

You might use also SPList.GetItemById or similar methods or even make a caml query against the target list w/ SPList.GetItems method. It's up to your particular situation and it would b nice if you can describe it.

SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile method is also ok, it really depends on your situation.